# Normal distribution sampling in pytorch-lightning

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

In **Pytorch-Lightning** you usually never have to specify cuda or gpu. But when I want to create a gaussian sampled Tensor using `torch.normal` I get

```
RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
```

so, how do I have to change `torch.normal` such that pytorch-lightning works properly? Since I use the code on different machines on cpu *and* on gpu

```py
centers = data["centers"] #already on GPU... sometimes...

lights = torch.normal(0, 1, size=[100, 3])
lights += centers
```

Comment: Just move it to the same device as one of the other tensors it will be interacting with. As you didn't post any code, it is hard to be more specific on what should be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recommended way is to do `lights = torch.normal(0, 1, size=[100, 3], device=self.device)` if this is inside lightning class.
You could also do: `lights = torch.normal(0, 1, size=[100, 3]).type_as(tensor)`, where `tensor` is some tensor which is on cuda.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.to('device_name')`:

```
lights = torch.normal(0, 1, size=[100, 3]).to(centers.device)
centers += lights
```

As you asked about pytorch-lightning is worth to mention that methods like `.to(...)` or `.type_as(...)` are not related to this framework as they coming from torch.