# How to use numpy dataset in Pytorch Lightning

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, pytorch-lightning

I want to make a dataset using `NumPy` and then want to train and test a simple model like 'linear, or logistic`.

I am trying to learn `Pytorch Lightning`. I have found a [tutorial](https://lightning-bolts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classic_ml.html#linear-regression) that we can use the NumPy dataset and can use uniform distribution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63660624/normal-distribution-sampling-in-pytorch-lightning). As a newcomer, I am not getting the full idea, how can I do that!

My code is given below

```
import numpy as np 
import pytorch_lightning as pl 
from torch.utils.data import random_split, DataLoader, TensorDataset
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torchvision import transforms

np.random.seed(42)

device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'

class DataModuleClass(pl.LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.constant = 2
        self.batch_size = 10
        self.transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor()
        ])
        
    def prepare_data(self):
        a = np.random.uniform(0, 500, 500)
        b = np.random.normal(0, self.constant, len(x))

        c = a + b
        X = np.transpose(np.array([a, b]))

        idx = np.arange(500)
        np.random.shuffle(idx)
        
        # Uses foirst 400 random indices for training
        train_idx = idx[:400]
        # Uses the remaining indices for validation
        val_idx = idx[400:]
        
        # Generate train and validation dataset
        x_train, y_train = X[train_idx], y[train_idx]
        x_val, y_val = X[val_idx], y[val_idx]
        
        # Converting numpy array to Tensor
        self.x_train_tensor = torch.from_numpy(x_train).float().to(device)
        self.y_train_tensor = torch.from_numpy(y_train).float().to(device)
        
        self.x_val_tensor = torch.from_numpy(x_val).float().to(device)
        self.y_val_tensor = torch.from_numpy(y_val).float().to(device)
        
        training_dataset = TensorDataset(self.x_train_tensor, self.y_train_tensor)
        
        validation_dataset = TensorDataset(self.x_val_tensor, self.y_val_tensor)

        return training_dataset, validation_dataset
        
    def train_dataloader(self):
        training_dataloader = prepare_data() # Most probably this is wrong way!!!
        return DataLoader(self.training_dataloader)

    def val_dataloader(self):
        validation_dataloader = prepare_data() # Most probably this is wrong way!!!
        return DataLoader(self.validation_dataloader)
        
    # def test_dataloader(self):
        
obj = DataModuleClass()
print(obj.prepare_data())
```

This part is done based on the answer given [Here, I want to take `a and b as features` and `c` as `label or target variable`.]

Now, how, can I pass the dataset into the `training and validation method?

Comment: I think you are not making instance of class, at the end write: obj = DataModuleClass(), then call obj.prepare_data()

Comment: Thank you it works. Now, if I want to use `a, and b` as features then how can I tell the mothed that these 2 are features and `c` is the target?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, can you please explain what functionality you want to perform with these 3 variables, a,b,c

Comment: I want to use `a and b` as features for training the model and `c` as the target variable. I also transformed `a, and b` into a tensor. Now, do I have to combine them? Because, we can pass 2 variable like `SklearnDataModule(X, y)` where, `X` is the all features variable and `y` is the target.

Comment: See, training in pytorch works with tensors, whereas in the above data numpy arrays are being created, so I would suggest you to go through a pytorch training guide which can help you in learning basics of pytorch and its working,

You can see this: https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-pytorch-with-an-example-a-step-by-step-tutorial-81fc5f8c4e8e

Comment: Thanks a lot. Hopefully, I will learn a lot from this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data from `prepare_data()` or `setup()` both using the following code.

```
def prepare_data(self):
    a = np.random.uniform(0, 500, 500)
    b = np.random.normal(0, self.constant, len(a))

    c = a + b
    X = np.transpose(np.array([a, b]))

    # Converting numpy array to Tensor
    self.x_train_tensor = torch.from_numpy(X).float().to(device)
    self.y_train_tensor = torch.from_numpy(c).float().to(device)

    training_dataset = TensorDataset(self.x_train_tensor, self.y_train_tensor)

    self.training_dataset = training_dataset

def setup(self):
    data = self.training_dataset
    self.train_data, self.val_data = random_split(data, [400, 100])

def train_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(self.train_data)

def val_dataloader(self):
    return DataLoader(self.val_data)
```

You can split the dataset using `random_split()`.

Answer (score 0):

This code will return you label as y and a,b as 2 features of 500 random examples merged into X.

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable

def prepare_data(self):
    a = np.random.uniform(0, 500, 500) # random feature 1 x 500
    b = np.random.normal(0, 2, len(a)) # random feature 2 x 500
    X = np.transpose(np.array([a,b]))  # Merging feature 1 and 2 x 500
    y = np.random.randint(0,2,len(a))  #  random Labels as 0 and 1
    X = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X).float())            # Converting numpy array X to Torch tensor with auto_grad enabled
    y = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y).float())            # Converting numpy array y to Torch tensor with auto_grad enabled
    return X,y
```

Answer (score 0):

Its just that you have to return torch tensors

```
import numpy as np 
import pytorch_lightning as pl 
from torch.utils.data import random_split, DataLoader

class DataModuleClass(pl.LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.constant = 2
        self.batch_size = 20
    self.transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor()
    ])
        
    def prepare_data(self):
        a = np.random.uniform(0, 500, 500)
        b = np.random.normal(0, self.constant, len(a))
        c = a + b
        
        return torch.from_numpy(a).float(), torch.from_numpy(b).float(), torch.from_numpy(c).float()
```

Comment: Thank you. After preparing the dataset I also need to pass them in the `train` and `validation` method. Say, I have `training_dataset = TensorDataset(self.x_train_tensor, self.y_train_tensor)` in my `prepare_data()` and I want to pass them into `train_dataloader()`. How can I do this?

Comment: I have edited my code based on your answer but still, I am trying to solve the problem.